# Prophet Dawood would sleep for half the night, then stand for a third, then sleep for another sixth

Tags: salat, tahajjud

But, if the night is at maghrib how do I sleep half of the night when there is Isha? Please only answer if you are smart in Islamic knowledge.

Comment: it would be better if you post your reference as well. what are you trying to imply here?. if what you seek is how to perform acts of worship at night, then our beloved prophet muhammad (P.B.U.H) has the best example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The night in Islam starts at Maghrib and ends at fajr. So you can divide the time between that. Also, It is important to note that at the time of Prophet Dawood (AS) there was no Maghrib, Isha, Fajr, etc. the Prophets (Peace Be Upon Them All) before Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) had different prayers with different names and perhaps at different times wallahua'lam.

Because the 5 salah that we pray were given to Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) from Allah at the night of mairaj there were no such "5 salah" at the times before Prophet Mohammad (PBUH).

Comment: This is to a huge part more guessing than anything else. I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: @Jamila What do you mean by guessing? It is an established fact that the prayers weren't the same at the times of other Prophets because Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) got them on the night of mairaj. Also, before Islam, the main calendar used was the gregorian calendar in which the day starts at 12 at the night and ends at 12 at the night too.

Comment: @Jamila On the night of Mairaj Prophet Musa (AS) told Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) that his people were given 50 salah a day to perform, which was what Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) and his ummah were essentially given. So Prophet Musa (AS) asked Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) to go back to Allah and ask him to lower the count of prayers and this process happened till the 5 prayers and Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) was shy to go back to Allah and ask him to lower It even more and then It was established that the ummah of Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) will have to pray 5 salah per day.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is wrong. He would sleep FOR half of the night not until midnight. We don't sleep after Maghrib but after Isha. So you would need to calculate the time between the time you go to sleep and Fajr, divide that by half, add this time to the time when you go to sleep, wake up at this time and pray, use the same time between the time you go to sleep and Fajr, divide by 3 and add this time to the time when you woke up, this is the time you go to sleep and then finally wake up for Fajr. I use the Time Calculator app to make these calculations, might make an app myself in the future In shaa Allah to make it easier for the ummah. https://islamqa.info/en/answers/194615/commentary-on-the-hadith-the-dearest-of-prayer-to-allah-is-the-prayer-of-dawood-peace-be-upon-him-he-used-to-sleep-for-half-the-night-get-up-and-pray-for-one-third-of-it-and-sleep-for-one-sixth-of-it